# How to view retrieved chunks from RetrievalQA chain

Tags: python, langchain, py-langchain

I want to see what chunks are being retrieved instead of simply seeing the final result. I have tried to put verbose=True but it gives no insight into the chunks being retrieved from my db.

```
embeddings = OpenAIEmbeddings()
db = FAISS.load_local("faiss_index_chunk_1000", embeddings)
retriever = db.as_retriever()    

qa_chain = RetrievalQA.from_chain_type(llm=chat, chain_type="stuff", retriever=retriever, verbose=True,chain_type_kwargs=chain_type_kwargs)

result = qa_chain.run(question)
```

I just get the final result but cannot print the chunks to analyse them.

Answer (score 0):

```
RetrievalQA.from_chain_type(llm=OpenAI(), chain_type="stuff", retriever=docsearch.as_retriever(search_kwargs={"k": 2}),chain_type_kwargs={
                "verbose": True})
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to this question! Could you add some context as why does this solve the issue? Part of the guidelines of this community is to help understand the solution and not provide a simple copy-paste solution :)